# zypper or yast unable to install third-party RPM from local repository

Tags: yum, rpm, yast, zypper

I am using a SLES11 SP4 machine, and trying to install an RPM from local yum repository.
All other RPMs which are provided by SUSE and copied in my local repository installs fine like mysql, samba etc.

The issue happens with a third-party RPM called mirthconnect, which is downloaded from http://downloads.mirthcorp.com/archive/connect/3.2.1.7650.b40/ and copied in my local YUM repository connected to my SLES11 SP4 machine.

```
SLES11SP4-118:~ # zypper se mirth
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...

S | Name         | Summary | Type
--+--------------+---------+-----------
  | mirthconnect | (none)  | srcpackage



SLES11SP4-118:~ # zypper install mirthconnect
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'mirthconnect' not found in package names. Trying capabilities.
No provider of 'mirthconnect' found.
Resolving package dependencies...

Nothing to do.
```

**ADDED**
I just now found, that zypper has a way to install source RPMs as below using `zypper si`

```
zypper si mirthconnect
Reading installed packages...
Loading repository data...
Resolving package dependencies...

The following items are locked and will not be changed by any action:
  Installed:
  cifs-utils erlang fam fuse jdk libMagickCore1 libiniparser0 libjasper libmysqlclient15 libmysqlclient_r15
  libnetpbm-devel libnetpbm10 libwmf mysql mysql-client netpbm nfs-kernel-server perl-DBD-mysql perl-DBI
  perl-Data-ShowTable perl-Net-Daemon perl-PlRPC postgresql-libs samba samba-32bit samba-client
  samba-client-32bit stunnel unixODBC
  Available:
  libtspi1

The following source package is going to be installed:
  mirthconnect

.
Overall download size: 137.5 MiB. After the operation, additional 155.2 MiB will be used.
Continue? [y/n/? shows all options] (y): y
Retrieving: mirthconnect-3.2.1.7650.b40-linux.x86_64.rpm [done] ….
```

But this mirthconnect is also part of dependency of another RPM, which needs it. When i try to install that using yast2 it says "Nothing provides mirthconnect"

Answer (score 0):

That is a *srcpackage*; you should get the normal package (ending with **.rpm** and not with **.src.rpm**)

Comment: It's actually not a source RPM, not sure why it shows it as. You can see, going to the link i have provided above `mirthconnect-3.2.1.7650.b40-linux.rpm`

Comment: did you try zypper in ./mirthconnect-3.2.1.7650.b40-linux.rpm

Comment: That RPM installs in itself, but it is also pulled in as dependency of another RPM, which uses mirthconnect in it's dependency list. When i install that, it says: Nothing provides mirthconnect" while trying to resolve dependency.

Comment: Edited my question to include what i mentioned in above comment.

Comment: as I said; this is a source rpm; which contains **source code** and not binaries. Yes you can install it (using zypper si); but that doesn't solve your dependency error... you need to get a **normal rpm** and get that one installed

Comment: you can also use the source rpm and rebuild the rpm you need using `rpmbuild --rebuild *.src.rpm`

Comment: As expected, got this error (since it is not a source package). rpmbuild --rebuild mirthconnect-3.2.1.7650.b40-linux.rpm
Installing mirthconnect-3.2.1.7650.b40-linux.rpm
error: source package expected, binary found
error: mirthconnect-3.2.1.7650.b40-linux.rpm cannot be installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41260/discussion-between-chris-maes-and-kingsmasher1).